# Use bash commands on a dataframe rather than a file r

Tags: r

I been trying to use some bash tools in R and its fine but I always seem to have to export my dataframe as a file before I can use the command on it. As you can imagine this is cluttering my system and I'd rather not have to export and then re-import files all the time.

As an example I'm doing this:

```
Repats<- Repats[grep("And*", Repats$V4), ]
write.table(Repats,"/mypath/And.bed",row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F, sep="\t")
system(paste("sed -i '' 's/\"//g'","/mypath/And.bed"))
Tedious<-read.delim("/mypath/And.bed"
```

When what I'd like to do is this:

```
Repats<- Repats[grep("And*", Repats$V4), ]
system(paste("sed -i '' 's/\"//g'","Repats"))
```

I just don't know how to refere to a dataframe as part of the system(paste argument

Comment: Why do you want to use bash tools? It looks like what you want to do could easily be done within R.

Comment: There are a bunch of tools that run in the terminal that R doesnt have. sed was given as an example but I also need to use genomic analysis tools (such as bedtools) which I dont think have R packages (equivalents exist but need to use bedtools for various reasons)

Comment: I'm not sure you'll ever actually avoid the step of creating a file. You can always "hide" it by putting the relevant R code in a function, which would at least reduce the amount of typing you do.